# When focus is on EditText GridView lagging

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-gridview

i have an issue which i cannot solve. Namely i have my own custom actionbar and below a gridview (of course this 2 parts have their own layouts). It looks like this img:

[My layout application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoxjL.jpg)

My edittext field search elements in gridview. Every img in gridview have an animation when is clicked.
My problem is when i click on edittext field and it is focused, then when i'm scrolling my gridview and even click on any item in both situations i've got about half second lags every few seconds. When edittext lose focus everything works great.

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have a bunch of images in your gridview.  I had this same problem with a really laggy UI/EditTexts when one of the images on my page was actually much larger than I was displaying it as.  I would suggest making sure the images you are displaying are not much larger than you really need them to be.

Comment: You are right with resolution of my image but not in gridview only in actionbar background. My resolution there was 1600x764..... i change this to much smaller and everything work great. Thanks for help